# How can i download this pic?

Tags: php, image

I have url, "comicsbook.ru/upload/13307036534f50ed2593fa8.jpg", but i can't parse this, NOT ONE of this methods wasn't successful: 
curl_init(),
file_get_contents,
copy.

Can some one help me? How do i can download this with php on my local?

Comment: What parts of the page do you want to parse? It's quite possible that the host has measures in place to stop scripts scraping the site.

Comment: I need only "comicsbook.ru/upload/13307036534f50ed2593fa8.jpg" this img. it's posible?

Comment: The link you gave redirects to a page with the image _contained within it_. You'll need to get that page's HTML, parse it and find the image source URL. What is likely to be happening is the site disallows image hotlinking by redirecting to a page with the image on it.

Comment: Give us more information about the attempts you made, such as developed code, errors thrown, results, etc.

Comment: I need to parse each imgage inside of <div class='lightbox'> on my local.
p.s. Sorry for my bad English =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do something the site admins didn't intend you to do? You should ask the admins before doing anything like this.

Anyway. This site seems to use the `Referer`header value to assess if you get the image or wil be redirected to a complete page. This code should help using cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Referer: http://comicsbook.ru/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if `allow_url_fopen` set to `true`
and use `fopen` to save the pic

this code should work. First test it with some other image. If it work with some other image then it should work with your image too.Other wise the check the image URL again.

```
$content = file_get_contents('comicsbook.ru/upload/13307036534f50ed2593fa8.jpg');
file_put_contents('/images/image.jpg', $content);
```

Comment: It's download empty image. screen: http://imagestore.com.ua/images/eoe.png

Comment: have you tested your code with image other than comicsbook.ru/upload/13307036534f50ed2593fa8.jpg

Comment: <?php 
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName("a") as $element){
 if(strstr($element->getAttribute("class"),"lightbox")){
  foreach($element->getElementsByTagName("img") as $pic){
  $img="http://comicsbook.ru".$pic->getAttribute("src");
  $name=explode("/",$img);
  $content = file_get_contents($img);
  file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/ru/".$name[sizeof($name)-1], $content);
  if(!is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/upload/ru/".$name[sizeof($name)-1])){
  
}}}}
?>